# Dependencies not satisfied: ros-indigo-gazebo5-msgs?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, buildfarm, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am releasing a package via Bloom into ROS Indigo that depends on `gazebo_msgs`. Since the Indigo-supported version of Gazebo `v2.x`, I am confused where the buildfarm is finding the dependency of `gazebo5_msgs`. How do I explicitly state that this package does not depend on `gazebo5_msgs`?

Relevant build failure snippit:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Need to get 1,263 B of source archives.
Get:1 http://repos.ros.org/repos/building/ trusty/main ros-indigo-baxter-sim-kinematics 1.2.1-0trusty (dsc) [1,263 B]
Fetched 1,263 B in 0s (27.5 kB/s)
Download complete and in download only mode
package ros-indigo-baxter-sim-kinematics does not have dependency [ros-indigo-gazebo5-msgs]
Dependencies not satisfied for packages: ['ros-indigo-gazebo5-msgs']
```

URL for complete buildfarm console output: 
http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-baxter-sim-kinematics_binarydeb_trusty_amd64/9/console 
URL for repo's package.xml: 
https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/baxter_simulator/blob/master/baxter_sim_kinematics/package.xml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223663/dependencies-not-satisfied:-ros-indigo-gazebo5-msgs?/) by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 790 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like the system that run bloom was configured to use [our rosdep overlay](https://github.com/osrf/osrf-rosdep/) typically used to release ROS wrappers for gazebo new versions not officially supported in ROS.

If you still have access to that system, you can easily verify it by running:

```
rosdep resolve gazebo_msgs
```

If this is the case, in order to use the standard ROS supported versions again, I would suggest to remove the 00-* files in `/etc/rosdep/sources.list.d` , run `rosdep update`and launch bloom again to generate a new -release version of your debian control files.

---

Originally posted by [jrivero](https://answers.ros.org/users/440/jrivero/) with karma: 138 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2016-01-15**:
The combination of yours and Tully's answers are absolutely spot on. I had the OSRF gazebo sources added to my sources list, but had not actually installed ros-indigo-gazebo5-msgs. Cleaning my environment of the OSRF sources, and then re-blooming worked like a charm. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

bloom uses your current environment to resolve packages. I'm guessing you've installed the OSRF overlayed gazebo backports of gazebo5 for indigo. I'm not sure off the top of my head of the exact mechanism, but I think the local packages on your path are used to resolve the dependencies.

You can see the results of the bloom process have baked in the dependency name here: https://github.com/RethinkRobotics-release/baxter_simulator-release/blob/debian/ros-indigo-baxter-sim-kinematics_1.2.1-0_trusty/debian/control#L11

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1